iOS: Rich push notification: .apns payload + simulator + (Notification Content Extension / Notification Service Extension never called
I wanted to try rich push notificatios. I made a test app. I wanted to test it through the simulator (saw that it is possible, also found a video where it works through Notification Content Extension - made the same steps and no effect).
My payload RichPush.apns:
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Testing title",
            "body" : "Testing message"
        },
        "category" : "content_added_notification",
        "sound" : "default",
        "badge" : 1,
        "mutable-content": 1
    },
    "attachment_url": "https://www.example.com/image_url",
    "Simulator Target Bundle" : "com.something.RichPush"
}

The push itself works, but only the alert with sound, badge, and without image

tried via service extension
tried via content extension

Both options don't work. I launch the app via the extension scheme by selecting my installed application. Then I dragged the payload into the simulator or send push via the console. I don't get into the extension code of current extention, breakpoints and prints don't work. It doesn't matter whether you implemented e.g. didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler(for 1) or sth in NotificationViewController(for 2) or not.
Copy only when installing is disabled. I tried in Xcode 15 and 16 with simulator. Target is correct: less than or equal to simulator version. I can't try it on device, and since we have video with simulator, I'm not sure that it is a problem, maybe i'm wrong)
Pls, any ideas on how to fix this or what I missed?
